# I want to write vue.js code in v-for, so this code should run every time while v-for is running.Is this possible?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

```
<div class="questions" v-for="(q,index) in questions " :key="index" {{this.idx+=1}} >
        <h3 >  {{q.content}}</h3>
        <h3> A) {{q.a}}  </h3>
        <h3> B) {q.b}} </h3> 
        <h3> C) {{q.c}} </h3>
        <h3> D) {{q.d}} </h3>
        <v-btn  :id="idx"  dark class="btn-right deep-purple darken-3" v-if="veritabani"  
@click="add(q)" > Add </v-btn>
       
</div>
```

the code i want to run {{this.idx+=1}}. I'm just waiting for it to work here I don't want it to print the result.

Comment: What is that you are trying to achieve with that extra `idx`? You already have another `index` that automatically increments. If you could help us understand how you use this `idx`, maybe we can find a proper way for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way one can think of can be to make a method that iterates through questions collections and increments the count of state idx, you can call that function once questions API promise is resolved or watch questions variables and run that method.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Interpolation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Interpolations) can be used to output some data to the page, not to execute some arbitrary code
2. Do not use `this` in templates
3. What you want is not possible. Modifying reactive data as part of the template rendering will lead to an infinite render loop and app crashing...